# Ubuntu semi-permanently disabled Bluetooth (and freaked me out)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, drivers, device-manager

A couple of months ago, I disabled my Bluetooth device from inside Ubuntu 10 (I forget which version specifically).

I then rebooted into Windows, only to find that the icon was gone. Curious, I went into Device Manager, and saw that there was nothing detected there either... and started panicking quite a bit! **No** error, **no** warning, nothing... it was plain gone, as if my computer never even had a Bluetooth module in the first place.

I tried reinstalling the driver, turning the switch on and off, etc., but nothing seemed to work. In my last bit of hope, I went into Ubuntu and was (to my relief) able to turn my Bluetooth back on, and it was recognized again in Windows.

The problem is since gone, and I will **not** try to reproduce it, but I never figured out the reason:

How could a device be "seen" in one OS, but not the other?

Comment: Just FYI, there's http://askubuntu.com/ as well for Ubuntu related questions.

Comment: @Jeff: I know, but it's not really Ubuntu-specific.